# T-SQL Variable in Where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to return the records in this case that have company ABC... and contact is null. It will not return anything when `@Contact` is null. Or any variable for that matter. Ideas?

```
DECLARE @Customer NVARCHAR(40) = 'ABC Company',
        @Contact NVARCHAR(40) = NULL

SELECT
    Company
FROM
    company
WHERE
    contact = @Contact AND customer = @Customer
```

Thanks,
EB

Comment: You can't get the `NULL` recode,when you use `=`

Answer (score 5):

NULL is special in that it means UNKNOWN.

A known value (contact) can never equal an unknown value. You need an OR statement to check if it's equal OR is null

```
where (contact = @Contact OR (contact is null AND @Contact is null))
and customer = @Customer
```

Maybe something like that?

Comment: Can you please expand a bit on that. Example of the OR statement?  Thanks

Comment: @EBaze The key is that NULL values cannot be compared to anything. If you want to equate 2 (or more) null values, you must use the "is null" expression for all of the compared values. You don't provide context but I'll guess that this is (or will be) a stored procedure you use for searching. If so, read Erland's discussion about the topic [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can write

```
WHERE
ISNULL(contact,'') = ISNULL(@Contact,'') AND customer = @Customer
```

this do a null check and if null,then value will be considered as empty string for comparison.

instead of null==null (Which gives false), ''=='' will be performed.

```
    if(null =null)
        print 'Equal'

    else 
        print 'not equal'
```

/*******************************************/

```
    if('' ='')
        print 'Equal'

    else 
        print 'not equal'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This part `ISNULL(contact,'')` recommends to read about [sargable predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/5089204)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, there is trivalent logic applied. In [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) you can read in detail about such logic. Bottom line is, that among true and false, there is another value: `UNKNOWNN`, which (in SQL) is the result of comparisons with `NULL` values. You can think of it as false (in this case).

Now, to visualise:

this queries won't return anything, as the `where` clause evaluates to `UNKNOWN`:

```
select 1 where null = 0
select 1 where null <> 0
select 1 where null = null
```

While this might be obvious, **there's consequence:** when you use `not in` operator.
When right operand contains `NULL`s, the query will return no records, e.g.:

```
select 1 where 0 not in (null, 1, 2)
```

won't return anything. **It's especially important when you put some query as right operand.**